# INI file - retrieve a section name by key name in VBS

Tags: vbscript, ini

I would like to retrieve a section name from an INI file with only a unique key name

My ini file :

```
...
[Area.104]
Title=Central North America
Local=Scenery\NAMC
Layer=104
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE

[Area.105]
Title=Eastern North America
Local=Scenery\NAME
Layer=105
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE

[Area.106]
Title=Western North America
Local=Scenery\NAMW
Layer=106
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE
...
```

How can I get section name [Area.105] from unique key Title=Eastern North America ???

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two ways of finding the required Area code:

**METHOD 1**

```
Option Explicit
Dim strFilePath, ofso, ofile, strFileData, strKey, strPrev, strCurr
strFilePath=""        '<-- Enter the absolute path of your .ini file in this variable

Set ofso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ofile = ofso.OpenTextFile(strFilePath,1,False)
strKey = "Eastern North America"             '<-- Enter Unique title for which you want the Area code

strPrev=""
strCurr=""
Do 
    strCurr = ofile.ReadLine
    If InStr(1,strCurr,strKey)<>0 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    strPrev = strCurr
Loop Until ofile.AtEndOfStream
MsgBox strPrev

Set ofile = Nothing
Set ofso = Nothing
```

**METHOD 2(Using Regular Expression)**

```
Option Explicit
Dim strFilePath, ofso, ofile, strFileData, strKey, re, objMatches
strFilePath=""           '<-- Enter the absolute path of your .ini file in this variable

Set ofso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ofile = ofso.OpenTextFile(strFilePath,1,False)
strFileData = ofile.ReadAll()
ofile.Close
strKey = "Eastern North America"     '<-- Enter Unique title for which you want the Area code

Set re = New RegExp
re.Global=True
re.Pattern="\[([^]]+)]\s*Title="&strKey
Set objMatches = re.Execute(strFileData)
If objMatches.Count>0 Then
    MsgBox objMatches.Item(0).Submatches.Item(0)
End If

Set re = Nothing
Set ofile = Nothing
Set ofso = Nothing
```

[>>>Click here for Regex Demo<<<](https://regex101.com/r/kW7TJZ/2)

**Regex Explanation:**

- `\[` - matches literal `[`
- `([^]]+)` - capture 1+ occurrence of any character which is not `]` in a group
- `]` - matches literal `]`
- `\s*` - matches 0+ white-spaces(which include the newline characters)
- `Title=` - matches the text `Title=`. This is then concatenated with the variable `strKey` containing the value of unique title.

Comment: Thank you so much Gurman, but how can I use your script with ADODB.Stream instead of scripting.FileSystemObject with Charset  to _autodetect_all ? Actually my ini file can be encoded in different charset code;

Comment: By default, `opentextfile` method opens the text file in ASCII format. To open it in UNICODE format, use this line: `Set ofile = ofso.OpenTextFile(strFilePath,1,False,1)`. More help here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately when the ini file is encoded as UTF-16LE it does not work with your method

Comment: Will get back to you if I find a solution for that. Meanwhile you can unselect this as the answer.