# VBS Get a section name from an INI file with only a unique key name with ADODB.Stream

Tags: vbscript, adodb, ini

I would like to find a section name from an INI file with only a unique key name using **ADODB.Stream** instead of scripting.FileSystemObject with Charset "_autodetect_all"

My ini file :

```
... 
... 
... 

[Area.104] 
Title=Central North America 
Local=Scenery\NAMC Layer=104 
Active=TRUE 
Required=FALSE

[Area.105]

Local=Scenery\NAME 
Layer=105 
Active=TRUE 
Required=FALSE 
Title=Eastern North America

[Area.106] 
Local=Scenery\NAMW 
Layer=106 
Title=Western North America 
Active=TRUE 
Required=FALSE 

... 
... 
...
```

How can I get section name [Area.105] from unique key Title=Eastern North 
America ??? Keys are in random order. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INI file - retrieve a section name by key name in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360950/ini-file-retrieve-a-section-name-by-key-name-in-vbs)

Comment: there is a big difference because I ask a code with ADODB.Stream.

Comment: It's almost as if you asked one question, got an answer that didn't quite fit and just decided to write another question in the hope someone would give you the answer. You even wrote any code, how about a [mcve]? As for a **big** difference, that's debatable. At the very least you should have modified your original question to include the `ADODB.Stream` requirement instead of creating a duplicate question.

Comment: Hello Lankymart, you are right I had to modify the original question before I post a new one, my bad sorry. I subscribed today to this website and I didn't find a way to edit my post, I'm not yet familiar with the system. The reply to my first question was excellent by the way.

Comment: If this is your first time on [so], welcome. I'd also recommend reading [ask] and also searching the site *(or using Google to search the site)* to make sure your question hasn't already been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer which I have got from another website (thank you very much omen999)

This code works perfectly with ADODB

```
Dim TitleName
TitleName = Array("Central North America")
Set IniStream=CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
IniStream.Open 
Inistream.Charset="_autodetect_all"
IniStream.LoadFromFile "Area.ini"
IniFile=IniStream.ReadText
PosEnd=InStrRev(IniFile,"]",InStrRev(IniFile,TitleName(0)))
PosStart=InStrRev(IniFile,"[",PosEnd)+1
Wscript.Echo Mid(IniFile,PosStart,PosEnd-PosStart)
IniStream.Close
```